# API запрос на курс обмена валют

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

Подскажите, разобраться, почему не проходит fetch запрос?

```js
fetch('https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?exchange&coursid=5')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    const usdExchangeRate = data.find(currency => currency.ccy === 'USD' && currency.base_ccy === 'UAH' && currency.sale);
    console.log(`Курс продажи доллара в ПриватБанке: ${usdExchangeRate.sale}`);
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Вроде всё правильно написал, а данные не возвращает. [API рабочий](https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?exchange&coursid=5). А в консоль что-то не возвращает, и что не так с `fetch` запросом не пойму.

Comment: если посмотреть в панель разработчика в Network, то там написано CORS

Comment: и как это обойти? это ведь публичное API

Comment: Никак, напишити им в поддержку пусть поправят `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`